# Upload video from iPhone to YouTube using ESSVideoShare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, upload, youtube

I'm trying to upload a video using Eternal Storm video share app. I downloaded the iOS sample project from the link below and tried uploading a video that I created on my phone using his sample project. Basically, everything seems to work except, the url comes back nil after trying to upload. I tried uploading the same video to the same youtube account and it worked from the iPhone's camera roll app.

Can someone help resolve?

Thanks

https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion

Comment: You setup all of the required access tokens and app ids ?